# groupby, then set column value based on another column (too many indexers)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    updated_at   type      source
0   2017-01-01   User     
1   2017-01-01   Inbound
2   2017-01-02   User
3   2017-01-02   Outbound
4   2017-01-03   Outbound
5   2017-01-03   User
```

I need to get rid of the rows where `type != User`, but then set the source for the row where `type == User` to the `type` of the row that I'm getting rid of. So far, I've tried doing a `groupby('updated_at)`, but I run into the error of setting a value on a copy. Also, `groupby('updated_at')` always returns just two rows.

Here's what I want the result to be:

```
    updated_at   type      source
0   2017-01-01   User      Inbound
2   2017-01-02   User      Outbound
5   2017-01-03   User      Outbound
```

NB: I have ~370,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the lines you are targeting are consecutive, you could use `shift`:

```
df["source"]=df["type"].shift(-1)
```

and then filter out lines where `type=="User"`

---

**EDIT**

Since the lines are not consecutive, unlike in your sample,

```
df=df.sort_values(["updated_at", "type"])
```

This will guarantee that for one TimeStamp type are always (1) Inbound/Outbound (2) User.
Then:

```
df["source"]=df["type"].shift()
```

and then filter out lines where `type=="User"`

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work. They weren't always consecutive, but adding `sort_values` did the trick. My df was a little more complicated that I actually said, but it ended up being:
`df["source"]=df.sort_values('type').groupby(['updated_at', 'operator_name'])['type'].shift(+1)`

Comment: looks like `sort_values` didn't work as planned. Still can't get `type` to be consecutive.
I thought another option might be to use `.groupby(...).agg('sum')`, but I don't know to use a separator in the `sum` function.

Comment: You should be more specific in what you mean by "but then set the source for the row where type == User to the type of the row that I'm getting rid of". As lines are not consecutive, what should be `source` in a row you keep? the field `type` of the last row you got rid of? Something else

Comment: Correct, I'm grouping by `updated_at`. We should only have one row for each date.

Answer (score 0):

split the dataframe and standardize them using the the same index.
Then announce the source column from the source

```
user = df.loc[df.type == 'User',:]
user.set_index('updated_at')
bound = df.loc[df.type != 'User',:]
bound.set_index('updated_at')
user['source'] = bound.type
```